# Tie tracking clicks link to a href syntax and image

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, tracking

I need help with this scenario:

> I have a tracking clicks link (provided by someone / mandatory) that I
>   want to tie it to a clickable image so that, when visitors click on
>   that image, they will enter another page of the website and all clicks
>   traffic be taken in consideration by that tracking link.

I'm a complete noob and I want to know if that is possible and how (some example) with HTML / java or anything else.

**Thank you in advance.**

Comment: I think you are probably looking for [Event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: Probably, but I cannot use the onclick event? Like <a href="http://website.page.com" onclick="????('http://tracking.link.com'); ????('http://tracking.link.com);"><img src="path.to.image"></a> ? Basically I want to access 2 links in the same time, one to transmit the data and one to access the other page.

Comment: I didn't get you completely but what I understood is you want is `<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'eventCategory', 'click', 'test click on category');" href="website.com/page"></a>`